# Moving all class variables to "this"

Tags: javascript, object

Here's part of my code:

```
    class Light {
        constructor(xpos,zpos,ypos,range,diffuser,diffuseg,digguseb,intensity,angle,exponent) {
            this.xpos = xpos;
            this.ypos = ypos;
            this.zpos = zpos;
            this.range = range;
            this.diffuser = diffuser;
            this.diffuseg = diffuseg;
            this.diffuseb = diffuseb;
            this.intensity = intensity;
            this.angle = angle;
            this.exponent;
[...]
```

Is there any way to move all given argument variables to `this` so I can access them later?

```
var lt = new Light(0,12,15,...);
alert(lt.zpos); //outputs '12'
```

I'm looking for a solution to put those 11 `this` lines to one

Comment: Youre talking about scope of the variable object.. can you give an example of use.. What is the problem?

Comment: I want to shorten the code, to make it run faster. I don't want all `this.*` in here, I'm just asking for a way to put it into one line

Comment: But thats why you put it in the constructor.. So there is no ambiguity and you only write it once...

Comment: Shorter code doesn't always mean that it will run faster. In therms of speed I think your current code is the best it can be for that.

Comment: minification is not a reflection of execution speed...

Comment: @malutki5200 - I wasn't aware of that. Thanks a lot, that helps me out.

Comment: @Pogrindis As above

Answer (score 0):

This does what you desire. The portion in `mapArgsToThis` which gets the argument names was taken from [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-arguments). `mapArgsToThis` would be a helper function you would use when you want to be lazy.

```js
var mapArgsToThis = function(func, args, thisPointer) {
  var argsStr = func.toString().match(/function\s.*?\(([^)]*)\)/)[1];
  var argNames = argsStr.split(',').map(function(arg) {
    return arg.replace(/\/\*.*\*\//, '').trim();
  }).filter(function(arg) { 
    return arg; 
  });
  var argValues = Array.prototype.slice.call(args);
  argNames.forEach(function(argName, index) { 
    thisPointer[argName] = argValues[index]; 
  });
};

var MyConstructor = function(xpos,zpos,ypos,range,diffuser,diffuseg,digguseb,intensity,angle,exponent) {
  mapArgsToThis(MyConstructor, arguments, this);
};

var myInstance = new MyConstructor(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0);

console.log(myInstance);
```

Even though this is a solution, I don't recommend it. Typing out the argument mapping to your `this` properties is good for your fingers and is easier for others to read and know what's going on. It also doesn't allow for any processing of the argument values prior to assignment onto `this`.